# Create Sqoop Hive Import Job

Tags: hadoop, import, hive, sqoop, hive-table

I successfully did an ad hoc import from an oracle table into Hive table using Sqoop. Now I want to create and save a Sqoop job with the exact parameters I used for the ad hoc import.

But if I say:

`sqoop job --create myjob  --import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://host.port/foo \
--username myUserName \
--password-file file:///myfile.pwd \
--table mytable \
--create-hive-table \
--hive-import \
--hive-database my_hive_db \
--hive-table my_hive_table \
--fields-terminated-by '|' \
--hive-drop-import-delims \
--m 1`

I get an ERROR:

`19/03/05 14:56:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for job:
19/03/05 14:56:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --import
19/03/05 14:56:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --connect
19/03/05 14:56:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: jdbc:mysql:@host:port/foo`

If I delete all the \ it still doesn't work.

How do I define a Sqoop job with all the necessary parameters for Hive import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing ***`space`*** between `--` and `import`.

***Try with below syntax:***

```
sqoop job --create myjob  -- import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://host.port/foo \
--username myUserName \
--password-file file:///myfile.pwd \
--table mytable \
--create-hive-table \
--hive-import \
--hive-database my_hive_db \
--hive-table my_hive_table \
--fields-terminated-by '|' \
--hive-drop-import-delims \
--m 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bash escape issue. There should be no space just after the backslack "\" characters at the end of the line. You can see the extra spaces with:

```
cat -A sqoop_script.sh
```

Comment: Not sure if it is spacing, but in that case you may also want to check the double space before --import, and initially consider removing the linebreaks and slashes and just put everything on 1 line to see if the command works functionally.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the example you provide is wrong, but I was always using a slightly different syntax where import was not a flag inside a job.

From the [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive), these 2 syntaxes seem familiar to me:

```
sqoop import (generic-args) (import-args)
sqoop-import (generic-args) (import-args)
```